# Derivative of diagonal function

Tags: derivatives, matrix-equations, least-squares

I'm working on a sightly modified least-squares method which must minimize the quantity:
$$
[Y-\text{diag}(\mu X^T)]^T\cdot [Y-\text{diag}(\mu X^T)]
$$
where $Y$ is a $n$-dimensional vector and $\mu$ and $X$ are $n$ by $n$ matrices.

I'm having problems calculating the derivatives with relation to $\mu$ explicitely in order to obtain the normal equations. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Let $w = [Y-\text{diag}(\mu X^T)]$, so that the quantity to be differentiated is $w^2$.

Also, let's denote the operation for turning a vector into a diagonal matrix as $W = \text{Diag}(w)$.

Then the derivative that you requested is:
$$
\frac {\partial w^2} {\partial\mu} = -2 W \cdot X
$$

In order to derive it, I'll use the handy $3^{rd}$ order hyper-diagonal tensor $\beta$, whose components are all zero except when $i\!=\!j\!=k$ then $\beta_{ijk} = 1$.

This tensor allows the diag/Diag operators to be expressed as
$$ \eqalign {
w &= \text{diag}(W) = \beta:W \cr
W &= \text{Diag}(w) = \beta\cdot w \cr
}$$

Okay, here we go
$$ \eqalign{
dw^2 &= 2 w\cdot dw \cr
     &= 2 w\cdot d[Y-\text{diag}(\mu X^T)] \cr
     &= 2 w\cdot d[Y-\beta:(\mu X^T)] \cr
     &= -2 w\cdot \beta:d(\mu X^T) \cr
     &= -2 W:d(\mu X^T) \cr
     &= -2 W:d\mu\cdot X^T \cr
     &= -2 W\cdot X:d\mu \cr
}$$
Finally, going from the differential to the derivative yields:
$$ \eqalign{
\frac {\partial w^2} {\partial\mu} &= -2 W \cdot X \cr
}$$